# Register for Text-To-Speech callback with AVSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: ios, speech

I am using Text to speech in iOS 7 (AVSpeechUtterance).

*Is there a way to register a callback which will be invoked upon completion of speech?*

I need to know so that I can disable a play button while speech is running and re-enable the button when the speech is done.

Comment: I haven't used this before, but it looks like you send an instance of AVSpeechUtterance to an AVSpeechSynthesizer in order to have the phone speak a string. Is that correct? If so, the AVSpeechSynthesizer you use has a `delegate` property you can set in order to get the callback methods. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate) are the callback methods you can use if you specify a `delegate`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Apple Doc, An `AVSpeechUtterance` is the basic unit of speech synthesis.

AVSpeechSynthesizer has a delegate : `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate`. 
This protocol contains interesting methods able to solve your problem. I quote:

**In Swift :**

```
speechSynthesizer(_:didCancelSpeechUtterance:)
speechSynthesizer(_:didContinueSpeechUtterance:)
speechSynthesizer(_:didFinishSpeechUtterance:)
speechSynthesizer(_:didPauseSpeechUtterance:)
speechSynthesizer(_:didStartSpeechUtterance:)
speechSynthesizer(_:willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:utterance:)
```

**In Objective C**

```
speechSynthesizer:didCancelSpeechUtterance:
speechSynthesizer:didContinueSpeechUtterance:
speechSynthesizer:didFinishSpeechUtterance:
speechSynthesizer:didPauseSpeechUtterance:
speechSynthesizer:didStartSpeechUtterance:
speechSynthesizer:willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:utterance:
```

Take a look on the [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate_Ref/index.html)